# Set culture globally for a Silverlight 4.0 client

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Date formatting has always been a pain because it defaults to the American MM/dd/yyyy. How do I set the default culture for a Silverlight 4.0 client? It would be best, but not essential, if this was based on the user's regional settings.

Applying a format string or converter to every date field is not ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [Localizing Silverlight-based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238(VS.95).aspx), it should explain your options. Also check out [StringFormat and CurrentCulture in Silverlight](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx) by Tim Heuer.